# ijwhost.dll exception when loading managed CLI C++ project compiled for /clr:netcore

Tags: c++, .net-core, c++-cli

I am running into an issue with my solution that is comprised of a native C++ application calling a managed C++ (CLR) that is in turn referencing a C# project.
(Typical native to managed bridge implementation)

The code compiles and runs successfully on my development machine. However once I move it to a staging server I get the following error:

```
Faulting application name: POC_MOCK.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x62c75fef
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.DLL, version: 10.0.14393.2990, time stamp: 0x5caeb859
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000884cb
Faulting process id: 0x1c9c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8927e8d0fe66f
Faulting application path: D:\test\POC_MOCK.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase.DLL
Report Id: cad1e77c-fe71-11ec-80fe-000c297ddf34
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Upon investigating the crash dump via winDBG, I saw that ijwhost.dll is causing an exception.

```
STACK_TEXT:  
00e2fc60 5e00c672     e06d7363 00000001 00000003 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x48
00e2fc90 5e001405     00e2fcb0 5e015750 00f58fe8 Ijwhost!_CxxThrowException+0x66
00e2fcdc 5e009d4c     013c0667 00000000 00f5dc20 Ijwhost!start_runtime_and_get_target_address+0x138
00e2fcf0 5e0b1fc5     c42602c1 00f5a430 00f5dc20 Ijwhost!start_runtime_thunk_stub+0xc
00e2fd10 01201041     9b12698d 73d9cf33 9b12698d CPPWrapper!CPPWrapper::CPPWrapper+0x45
00e2fd30 0120159c     00000001 00f5a430 00f58fe8 POC_MOCK!main+0x41
00e2fd78 74bd6a14     7f218000 74bd69f0 eefe366c POC_MOCK!__scrt_common_main_seh+0xfa
00e2fd8c 7712a9ff     7f218000 ed2f7874 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
00e2fdd4 7712a9ca     ffffffff 7710fdc7 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
00e2fde4 00000000     01201624 7f218000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  D:\a\_work\1\s\src\installer\corehost\cli\ijwhost\ijwthunk.cpp
FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  D:\a\_work\1\s\src\installer\corehost\cli\ijwhost\ijwthunk.cpp
FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  153

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
No source found for 'D:\a\_work\1\s\src\installer\corehost\cli\ijwhost\ijwthunk.cpp'

SYMBOL_NAME:  ijwhost!start_runtime_and_get_target_address+138
MODULE_NAME: Ijwhost
IMAGE_NAME:  Ijwhost.dll
STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xe2f920 ; kb
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  FAIL_FAST_FATAL_APP_EXIT_CPP_EXCEPTION_c0000409_Ijwhost.dll!start_runtime_and_get_target_address
OS_VERSION:  6.3.9600.18217
BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_ltsb
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86
OSNAME:  Windows 8.1
IMAGE_VERSION:  5.0.1722.21314
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b2047410-307d-cb83-9a4d-78b763edf2d5}
Followup:     MachineOwner
```

I have no idea why Ijwhost::start_runtime_and_get_target_address is failing.
This seems to be a bit different than most of the issues I was able to find via google and on StackOverflow, so having tried some of the suggestions there didn't work for me.
ijwhost.dll does exist after a successful build and is next to the .EXE and .DLLs.

As seen in the above stack trace, the issue is happening when CPPWrapper is being constructed, and I took out all the references to anything C# and still got the error.

So just trying to call the constructor of the CLR DLL is where it goes bad.

Any hints, feedback is greatly appreciated!

**Dev. evn.:**
Win 10 professional, VS2022, VC++ v143, .NET6 and .NetCore 3.1

**Staging env.:**
Win Server 2012, required packages installed for the project to work and confirmed .net core 3.1 is installed for both x86 and x64 to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to loading ijwhost.dll (via LoadLibrary with explicit directory) immediately before loading the C++/CLI dll but there may be a better solution.